# how do i add a search bar for a listview.Builder with a json file?

Tags: json, flutter, searchbar

in my application Flutter I have a widget with this body

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text(data[index]['name']),
                leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                onTap: () => {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, data[index]['routes'])
                  // Your Logout method
                },
                //title: Text(data[index]['name']),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

the variable data depends on a local json file.
The json file is like this:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "name",
        "routes" : "/routes1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "name2",
        "routes" :  "/routes2"
    },
]
```

For update json file I use this code

```
Future<String> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.json');
    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(jsonText);
    });
    print(jsonText);
  }

  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void initState() {
    this.loadJsonData();
  }
```

with this code I have a list that makes me see the name and through 'routes' sends me to another page.

I need to add a search bar, which allows me as I type a name to display only similar ones.
For example if the list names in the json file are:
Martin
Mike
James

When I start typing 'M' I will see a list with
Martin
Mike.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The search and listview has to communicate by any state management. How do you manage your state. bloc library, provider, or something else or nothing at all?

Comment: @Error280MonkeyFound I don't know how to start doing the search bar, just because I don't know how to make them "communicate"

Comment: I'm not in front of a comp. I'll try to post in 2-3hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the list is local and will not change. The search can be achieved by using a simple stateful widget.

The most simple way would be to add a variable in state for filter names and set state with  filter names based on the search text. Here I have used a string item please use a class that fits your need.

`allNames` variable contains all the names.

`searchedNames` variable contains all the names.

`_searchChanged` function setsState with searchedName based on test entered in `TextField`

```dart
// Widget for searching through a string list.
class SearchNameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchNameWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchNameState createState() => _SearchNameState();
}

class _SearchNameState extends State<SearchNameWidget> {
  // All names
  List<String> allNames = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
    'six',
    'seven',
    'eight',
    'nine',
    'ten'
  ];

  // searched names
  List<String> searchedNames = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
    'six',
    'seven',
    'eight',
    'nine',
    'ten'
  ];

  // changes the filtered name based on search text and sets state.
  void _searchChanged(String searchText) {
    if (searchText != null && searchText.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        searchedNames =
            List.from(allNames.where((name) => name.contains(searchText)));
      });
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        searchedNames =
            List.from(allNames);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demos'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            // calls the _searchChanged on textChange
            onChanged: (search) => _searchChanged(search),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: searchedNames.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Text(searchedNames[index]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Benn, feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: I understand your explanation. I would like the list of my names to be seen anyway even without searching for anything.

Comment: For that you can set initial data for searchedNames as allNames. Also if you want all the names to be displayed while the search is empty add a else part `searchChanged` method. I have edited the code like wise. please do check.